# Angular Bootstrap Progressbar not updating when using with binded progress function

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am uploading a file to and IPFS node, which uses a progress function to handle updates. As you can see, I binded **this** to the handler function so it could access all the necessary variables

```
//This method controls uploading the waveform to IPFS
uploadWaveform()
{
    this.ipfs.files.add(buf, {progress:this.handler.bind(this)})
      .then((result) => {
          console.log("All done!");
          this.progressText = "All Done!";

    });
}
```

The progress handler function is a simple function which just updates the uploadProgress variable and looks like this:

```
handler (p) {    
  this.uploadProgress = Math.round(100*p/this.fileSize);      
}
```

I am using an angular ng-bootstrap progress bar like so:

```
<ngb-progressbar [value]="uploadProgress">
  <i>{{progressText}}</i>
</ngb-progressbar>
```

When I upload a file, it uploads correctly and the progress function works correcly.

However, the uploadProgess variable is not updated in the ng-bootstrap progress bar. If I click anywhere inside the application is will update the value, but not before then.

I know that it is actually updated inside the component because if I put a timeout to print out the value of the progressText 5 seconds after when the upload has completed it reflects the updated value!

```
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("this.progressText = " + this.progressText);
      }, 5000);
```

Anybody have any ideas why the component is not updating? I assume it is some weird binding problem... Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kousic This is for angular not angularjs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe the progress callback function `handler` is called out of angular, you can update `uploadProgress` in `NgZone` callback.

First inject `NgZone` instance in the constructor of your component

```
constructor (private zone: NgZone) { }
```

And then uodate your `uploadProgesss` in the `handler` function like this

```
handler (p) {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.uploadProgress = Math.round(100.0 * p / this.fileSize);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap progress with create a function in the ts to calculate percentage complete.

```
  <div ngClass="progress">
    <div ngClass="progress-bar progress-bar-success" 
         role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [style.width]="getPercentage()+'%'" >
      <div class="pl-2">{{getPercentage()}} %</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the function in component should should value of the percentage completed. When ever there is any update in the code angular will reload the function to get updated value.

```
complete=0
 getPercentage() {
return Math.round(100*this.complete/this.fileSize);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NgZone 'https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-ngzone'

```
handler (p) {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.uploadProgress = Math.round(100.0 * p / this.fileSize);
  });
}
```